# How to make this code work without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I have a code that looks like this:

```
$('a.guide-item[href="/"]').remove();
$('*[href="/"]').attr('href','/feed/subscriptions/u');
```

I need to make the file size smaller, but I don't know how to replicate the code in "vanilla" javascript. Please help!

Comment: this would be quite challenging to do without jquery.

Comment: This is why I posted the question, hoping that someone knows how.

Comment: what steps have you taken to rewrite it?

Comment: @DanielA.White: Quite challenging?

Comment: @DanielA.White I didn't take any steps because I don't know where to start.

Comment: @DJDavid98: Do you know how to loop over a set of elements, and how to set an Attribute?

Comment: @IHateLazy No. I got used to jQuery, and never got to learn any of these.

Comment: Start with `document.getElementsByTagName('a')`, loop over the results you get and filter for this that have the relevant `class` and `href` attributes. If you get stuck, provide the code you have in the question and we'll have a look.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without supporting IE6/7, it's very simple.

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll('a.guide-item[href="/"]');

for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    if (els[i].parentNode)
        els[i].parentNode.removeChild(els[i]);
}

els = document.querySelectorAll('*[href="/"]');

for (i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    els[i].setAttribute('href','/feed/subscriptions/u');
}
```

If you need to support IE6/7, it's still very simple, but it would be helpful to have a method that selects elements by class, or at least that tests for a class.

Not hard to find  implementations of these on the web.

---

Here's a quick implementation that will support older IE.

```
var els = document.links,
    i = els.length;

while (i--) {
    if (els[i].getAttribute("href") !== "/")
        continue;

    if (els[i].className.indexOf("guide-item") !== -1) {
        els[i].parentNode.removeChild(els[i]);
    } else {
        els[i].setAttribute('href','/feed/subscriptions/u');
    }
}
```

It assumes that the `.className` won't have other classes where `"guide-item"` would be matched as a sub-pattern.

Comment: Actually, I get an error: `Cannot call method 'removeChild' of undefined` on `els[i].parentNode.removeChild(els[i])`

Comment: @DJDavid98: Then some of the elements must have been nested or something. I'll update the first solution, but yes, the second will work either way.